# Complex lookup with fixed row and dynamic column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

Here is an example of what I want to achieve:

`Quarter` is selected in `G1`. This applies to periods `1, 4, 7, 10` as can be found in `C2:C5`. In `J2` I need a formula which checks if `I2` is equal to one of those four values mentioned before and which can be found in `column C`. Therefore, I have to first lookup the respective column of `Quarter` in `A1:D4` and then based on this check if this column contains the value in `I2`. If this is the case then `I2` should be written in `J2` else `0`.

My problem is how can I dynamically reference the respective column of the selected period in my formula? For `Quarter` I need to check if`I2` is in `C2:C5`, but for `Half-Year` the column changes to `B2:B5`. If possible, I want to avoid a complex IF formula for that part.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the formula for cell J2:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(I2,INDEX(A$2:D$13,,MATCH($G$1,A$1:D$1,)),),I2),)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

A shorter formula and no IFs:

```
=VLOOKUP(I2,A$1:D$13,MATCH(G$1,A$1:D$1,0),0)
```

**if** :) prepared to rearrange `A1:D13`:

[image]

Comment: Yes thanks a lot another great solution! I could not Figure out that I First have to look up I2 and then Period.